# Li-Po battery ritual when using first time

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lipo

We are using lithium-ion polymer battery in our project. The battery manufacturer recommends that battery needs to be fully charged and discharged for four times before usage as to reach its maximum battery performance.

Is this necessary to do and I am unable to understand the logic behind this ritual. Why not all battery manufacture write it in their user guide.

Comment: Depends. NiMH has a very strong effect of the initial cycles which forms the battery internally. Measure the internal resistance before and after, report back and draw your own conclusions about the forming process.

Comment: You should accept good answers...

Answer (score 5):

It is called break-in/conditioning process.

Lithium batteries have a chemical stabilizer layer applied by manufacturers in order to give them a long shelf life and also serves as a reaction brake.

We use the break-in procedure to break down this chemical.

Using them without the break-in procedure there will be huge increase in internal resistance which results in reduction of performance, health and life cycles of battery.

To properly bring your new Li Po battery up to speed we have to go charge and discharge it for 3 to 4 times.

Follow this [URL](http://s3fpv.com/wiki/index.php?title=Conditioning_New_Batteries) for the process of break-in with some examples.